# Auto run StatefulWidget with out onPressed

Tags: flutter

I'm having code below

```
        onPressed: () {
            ShowAlert(
                message: Text,
                context: context,
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.check,
                ));}
```

My `ShowAlert`

```
class ShowAlert<T> extends StatefulWidget{
     .....
}
```

I mean when user `onPressed`, the app will show small alert.
Now I want the alert will auto show with out press button.

How can I do that?

Comment: show based on time?

Comment: Call your code in initState function

Comment: @Programmer_3 I tried but it not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a class to display your `dialog`. Ex: Place this in a file called Dialog.dart:

```
class Dialog{
  static showMyDialog(
    BuildContext context,
  ) async {
    await showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("title"),
            content: Text("label"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  child: Text(
                    "Action",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  )),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

If you want to display it once your widget is building:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   Dialogs.showMyDialog(context); //add this
   return Scaffold(
   ...
  }
```